# Atualizar v-for em Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Eae pessoal, estou com um leve problema aqui no meu Vue.js. Tenho uma variavel `user.activeItems`, no HTML eu dou um v-for nessa variavel, para mostrar os itens ativos, da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="item-container" v-for="(item, index) in user.activeItems" :key="index">
    <item-active :act-index="index" :name="item.name" :description="item.description"></item-active>
</div>
```

Até ai esta tudo tranquilo, quando o usuario não tem nenhum item ativo, ele simplesmente não faz o v-for. Porem, em outra parte do meu App, tem um component que ativa um item ao ser clicado, ele adiciona o item ativo dessa seguinte maneira:

```
Vue.set( this.$root.user.activeItems, this.item_id, this.item );
```

Quando eu imprimo o `user.activeItems` já com um item atívo, ao adicionar outro, funciona tudo muito bem, porem se eu imprimir a variavel vazia e então adicionar um item, não acontece nada, o item é adicionado no `user.activeItems` porem não aparece no v-for.

Se alguem puder me ajudar, ficaria agradecido.

Comment: insere os itens do v-for utilizando um computed properties pois eles emitem modificações para o v-for sempre que acontece uma mudança nos itens

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que a aplicação deva estar quebrando devido não conseguir renderizar um item vazio.

Voce pode tentar fazer uma verificação nos items da sua lista, usando o `v-if`, e renderizar os items somente se existirem.

```
<div class="item-container" v-for="(item, index) in user.activeItems" 
:key="index">
   <item-active v-if="item" :act-index="index" :name="item.name" :description="item.description"></item-active>
</div>
```